# Can't connect to my dockerized MySQL/MariaDB Nodejs

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, docker, mariadb

I'm using docker to running MariaDB and deploy on openshift. I'm using this command to forward port to my local port.

```
oc port-forward mariadb-sdxcvv 13306:3306
```

And in my node project. I'm connect to mariadb via package mariadb. Here is my code:

```
  this.conn = await mariadb.createConnection( {
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    user: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PWD,
    database: process.env.DB_NAME,
    port: process.env.DB_PORT
  } );
```

And I get this error

```
Access denied for user 'admin'@'127.0.0.1' (using password: NO)
```

Here is my grant access for user in mariadb container

```
| User  | Host      |
+-------+-----------+
| admin | 127.0.0.1 |
| root  | 127.0.0.1 |
| root  | ::1       |
| admin | localhost |
| root  | localhost |
+-------+-----------+


+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for admin@127.0.0.1                                                                                                              |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'admin'@'127.0.0.1' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*EA3E87A342924C7419B8D1400798D4E63FBF0930' WITH GRANT OPTION |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Where is my wrong? Please help me

Comment: Can you try changing your user's host to `%` from 127.0.0.1 in your grant command?

Comment: @Edrian i have change it and still get this error

Comment: Can you console log the process.env.DB_PWD? Is it possible that it's empty?

Comment: @Edrian no it not empty

Comment: Oh. You need to run `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` after doing the `%` change you made earlier. See if that fixes it.

Comment: @Edrian yes, I already run it ,but it still get this error

Comment: Nodejs running inside container?

Comment: @Adiii no outside

Comment: Okay how you start db container?

Comment: @Adiii I deploy it on openshift and forward port to my local port. I can connect DB by mysql workbench but cannot connect via nodejs

Comment: Then it's mean connection string is not valid, try with hard coded value instead of picking from env